Why my Elasticsearch request doesn't show any hits?
I have dockerized Django project. I want to use Elasticsearch, so I choosed django-elasticsearch-dsl. My steps were:

In my Django project's settings file (settings.py), I configured the Elasticsearch connection settings.

ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': ["http://localhost:9200"],
    },
}


Created a file named documents.py my Django app. In this file, I defined Elasticsearch documents that correspond to my Django models.

from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry


from .models import Filmwork

@registry.register_document
class FilmWorkDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        name = 'film'
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1, 'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Filmwork 
        fields = ['title', 'description']


So then I indexed data from my Django model into Elasticsearch by using command python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild. I used this command outside docker, it showed:

File "/Users/ArtemBoss/Desktop/artem_yandex_repo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "database" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

At the same time, when I'm trying to index data inside django container it shows:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 202, in perform_request
    raise err from None
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9150762b60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused))

Anyway Index was successfully created, but when I send the request http://localhost:9200/film it shows no hits, like there are no documents:
{"film":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"properties":{"description":{"type":"text"},"title":{"type":"text"}}},"settings":{"index":{"routing":{"allocation":{"include":{"_tier_preference":"data_content"}}},"number_of_shards":"1","provided_name":"film","creation_date":"1714573697677","number_of_replicas":"0","uuid":"wtFsSoZUSXC73s5ScCbc2w","version":{"created":"8503000"}}}}}

What's the problem?

Try to send the request http://localhost:9200/film/_search

From what i've gathered, postgres and elastic are also running as containers, probably as docker-compose services.
The first error (when you are trying to index records running search_index --rebuild on the host) suggest it can't find the db. From the second error i've gathered DB settings are properly defined to bootstrap django and  networking is setup between containers.
You need to update the elastic setting so elastic can be accessed from the django container. Something like the following will do:
ELASTIC_HOST = "<name of the elastic service>"
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': [f"http://{ELASTIC_HOST}:9200"],
    },
}

